# Robot Model in rviz problems

Tags: ros, gazebo, rviz, urdf, tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Work though the urdf [tutorials](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf/Tutorials) but keep getting errors that visually wrong results. Every link has the error "No transform from [...name...] to [/base_link]"

For example when trying to see the turtlebot model from turtlebot_description I get:
[image: image description]

What am I missing? I have [urdf_tools](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf_tools).

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10593/robot-model-in-rviz-problems/) by [patrick_hammer](https://answers.ros.org/users/465/patrick_hammer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 283 on 2011-07-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You probably need to start either the [robot_state_publisher](http://www.ros.org/wiki/robot_state_publisher) which converts joint_states + urdf into a number of TF transforms, or the [joint_state_publisher](http://www.ros.org/wiki/joint_state_publisher) which will output joint_states for a robot when not connected to real hardware which does so.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6